Is there a film (or other work) "Pictures of the Sea" referenced by Al DiMeola album?
Jazz/rock fusion guitarist Al Dimeola's 1976 album Land of the Midnight Sun features a track called "Love Theme from Pictures of the Sea". It is mostly instrumental, with a bit of a vocal interlude. The title and style suggest that it might have been part of the sound track of some film project (which would obviously be "Pictures of the Sea"), or a cover of such a work, but searches about this come up with nothing.
Is it really a theme "from" something like its title says (like perhaps some friend's obscure movie project), or was it just wistfully named to suggest such a thing?

I notice that the preceding track on the album is "Sarabande from Violin Sonata in B Minor", so it's possible that the "from" means it was taken from existing suite called "Pictures of the Sea" rather than a film soundtrack.

@Kaz - We are currently discussing on whether to keep identification questions.  https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5033/49

@Valorum This doesn't exactly fit the pattern of those questions and isn't attracting low-quality posts. It's starting to look as if it's something only the artist would know or surrounding people from that time, not answerable without sending some e-mails. You'd think that makes for good Q&A; why wouldn't you want a question and answer on the site, which cannot be found anywhere else.

@Kaz - Indeed. I personally think this is a fine question and should be kept. I was merely pointing out that there are others who feel differently.

@Kaz I agree—this isn't an off-topic, low-quality ID question. While two users have already voted to close it as an ID question (which is likely what prompted Valorum's comment), I've voted to keep it open. It could lead to interesting, hard-to-find information and add value to our knowledge base.

@galacticninja It could turn out to have nothing to do with movies or TV; but that is not known yet.
